# Compress image in tiff viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, tiff

I have created Tiff file viewer for my web application and it's working great. But the problem is there are some big images (4000 X 2000 - 5+ MB) which I need to display in it's original size.

Is it possible to compress the size of the image and then send the stream to Response Stream on the ashx page?

Note that all my images are scanned black and white images. However for precaution I would like to check whether compression algorithm specific to black & white image be applied to the  image or not.

Look the below code of TiffHelper class

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

public class TiffHelper
{
    public static int GetPageCount(String filePath)
    {
        int pageCount = 0;
        try
        {
            using (Image img = Image.FromStream(
                                new FileStream(filePath,
                                 FileMode.Open,
                                 FileAccess.Read,
                                 FileShare.ReadWrite)
                           ))
            {
                pageCount = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CException.SuppressException(ex);
            pageCount = -1;
        }

        return pageCount;
    }

    public static Image GetTiffImage(String sourceFile, int pageNumber, int thumbnailSize, int degree)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = null;
        Image sourceImage = null;
        Image returnImage = null;

        try
        {
            sourceImage = Image.FromStream(
                                new FileStream(sourceFile,
                                 FileMode.Open,
                                 FileAccess.Read,
                                 FileShare.ReadWrite)
                           );
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            FrameDimension FrDim = new FrameDimension(sourceImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
            sourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrDim, pageNumber - 1);

            sourceImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);

            /*
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 90);
            ImageCodecInfo tiffCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

            sourceImage.Save(ms, tiffCodec, encoderParams); 
            */

            /*
            EncoderParameters iparams = new EncoderParameters(2);
            iparams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
            iparams.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
             * 
            sourceImage.Save(ms, GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff"), iparams);
            */

            int height = sourceImage.Height;
            int width = sourceImage.Width;

            if (thumbnailSize > 0)
            {
                if (sourceImage.Width < sourceImage.Height)
                {
                    width = thumbnailSize;
                    height = sourceImage.Height * thumbnailSize / sourceImage.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    width = sourceImage.Width * thumbnailSize / sourceImage.Height;
                    height = thumbnailSize;
                }
            }

            //returnImage = ResizeImage(Image.FromStream(ms), new Size(width, height));

            returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms).GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            returnImage.RotateFlip(GetFlipType(degree));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CException.SuppressException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            ms.Dispose();
            sourceImage.Dispose();
        }

        return returnImage;
    }

    private static Image ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);

        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
            {
                return codecs[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static RotateFlipType GetFlipType(int degree)
    {
        switch (degree)
        {
            case 90:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;
            case 180:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
            case 270:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone;
            case -90:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY;
            case -180:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone;
            case -270:
                return RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipXY;
            default:
                return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed this commented out line in your code? `iparams.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);`?  CCITT4 is a compression format for black/white images.

Comment: Are your source files in TIFF GroupIV format? If not you are better off just compressing those rather than doing it in realtime in code.

Comment: Yes, I commented those lines as they were making no difference in image size. Btw, how am I supposed to know whether TIFF resides in GroupIV format? And how am I supposed to compress it?

Comment: Open them in a tiff viewer and look at the image properties. Alternately, you may be able to see the compression type in Windows if you view properties on the file.